# Office Outlook, disable GIF animations

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Outlook now plays animated GIFs in email bodies. [The desktop thick client]

According to - https://www.litmus.com/blog/microsoft-expands-animated-gif-support-with-outlook-365/

- GIFs will automatically play. Looping GIFs will play three times, after which they will pause (but can be played again manually by users).
- Animations will be enabled by default but can be turned off in Outlook settings.

Cannot find any setting or even mention of it on Microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree, disable the "Show animations in Windows" (Start-> Settings-> Ease of Access-> Display-> Show animations in Windows
)could help make GIFs not automatically play in Outlook.[image]

Comment: I don't know what else such a global setting will impact, but it did stop the GIFs in Outlook. There has to be a better way!

Answer (score 1):

As of Dec 2022, does not seem to be readily doable to disable gif-animations in outlook desktop client (alone, without affecting other system settings).

Consider upvoting my request for the feature in Outlook from microsoft, if you too want to be able to disable them:

https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/e055e2dd-af6a-ed11-a81b-6045bdaf6a9e

Answer (score 0):

Go to Outlook, Options (File, Options) and then go to Trust Center.

Expand Trust Center (right side button) and ensure Automatic Download is check (or the options within you need to check)

In Attachment Handling, turn OFF Automatic Preview.

These settings should stop the automatic playing of GIF images, but do check through all Trust Center settings.

If the Outlook Trust settings do not affect your email, then you may need to contact the sender of the mail and ask them.

Also "GIF Image Spam" used to be very common, and the sender may be exploiting these tactics.

Finally, look at Windows Settings to stop this. This is for Office animations and may or may not help you. It does primarily remain a sender issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-off-office-animations-9ee5c4d2-d144-4fd2-b670-22cef9fa025a

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That did not help with the GIFs; it only disabled all the helpful document previewers that I wanted.

Comment: So at this point it is probably a sender issue and you need to contact them. I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Further investigation to assist you suggests there is a Windows Setting to assist with this. This is for Office Animations and may or may not help you.